# What to follow OpenID vs Oauth(v1 & v2)?

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, openid

I have noticed that all the big websites are using `Openid` instead of `Oauth`.

I have my implementation of `oauth` for both `Google` and `Facebook`.

My requirement :

- Authenticate the users with Google / Facebook
- Manage simple user profiles for the users on my website, pre-populated from Google/Facebook.

What should I go for `Oauth` or `Openid` ?

When to follow `oauth` ?

Comment: What you are looking for is both OpenID and OAuth.

Comment: OAuth is *NOT* for authentication. OAuth is *ONLY* for delegation of rights.

Comment: "for both authentication and authorization." --- it is not 100% correct. OAuth is only for authorization. Authentication is available **only** if current token and/or server allows (*authorizes*) to authenticate. So it is possible to has a token that allows you to perform some actions, but doesn't allow you to perform authentication.

Comment: Ya, I understand that its not for both - But you need to authenticate when you want to authorize ? Isn't that correct ?

Comment: Just comprised all the information got. Hope this [OpenID & OAuth Comparison](http://techastute.blogspot.com/2012/05/openid-authentication-oauth.html) is useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are used for different goals.

OpenID is used to authenticate *SomeUser* on your site, asking some other site for the proof of the user's identity.

OAuth is used to grant *SomeOtherParty* (e.g. other site or application) a permission to do something on behalf of *SomeUser* on your site (this implies that *SomeUser* is already somehow authenticated on your site).

Some more comments, for the author's request:

You cannot choose "OAuth to authenticate users", since OAuth is not a user authentication protocol (despite the 'auth' in its name).

With OpenID you can authenticate a user with virtually *any* OpenID provider without any modifications to your code.

If you choose to *authenticate users using Facebook OAuth*, you are not actually authenticating users. You are asking users to get your application some access to user's profile on the facebook. You are *accessing Facebook services to fetch user information*. This means, that if you want to use another OAuth provider service to *authenticate* users, you will *never* be able to do it without writing new "authentication" code (except for the case when the new providers supports APIs identical to facebook).

Comment: +1 for correctness. I would also add though that the assertion made by the OP: "all the big websites are using Openid instead of Oauth" is not true. OAuth has gained more traction at this point than OpenID.